# How can I determine if the current scenario is N-th?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am using `Scenario Outline` with `Examples`. `Examples` have many rows. E.g. 10 rows.  I have an `After` hook where I check the outcome of scenario `passsed or failed` and write it to a file. Now I need to save and close that file after executing the final row. How can I determine if the current scenario is the last one?

Comment: one option is to tag the last example separately (say, @last), and have an After("@last") hook.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to tag the last example explicitly and have an After hook for that tag, as follows:

```
@others
Examples:
|input|
| abc |
| xyz |
@last
Examples:
|input|
| pqr |

@After("@last")
public void afterScenario() {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need something like an @AfterAll Hook, this is currently not supported in cucumber, but you can use this workaround which uses a jvm shutdown hook. :

```
static void addShutdownHook(WebDriver driver) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // DO STUFF LIKE SAVING YOUR FILE
            driver.quit();
        }
    });
}
```

Full example included in the shared driver example: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-webbit-websockets-selenium/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/websockets/SharedDriver.java